# Webcam.set() not showing but Webcam.snap() works

Tags: javascript, html, webcam, webcam-capture, webcam.js

I'm currently new to javascript and I'm attempting to learn to set my webcam and have it take a snap using js.
However, only the Webcam.snap() works on my end. My Webcam.set() and Webcam.attach() won't show despite being able to take a snapshot.

Here's how it looks like when [the page loads up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO43Q.png) vs after [I take a snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ1Dv.png)

The empty space on the left part is where the webcam is supposed to be positioned at

Here's my webcam part in html:

```
                <h3>Photo capture</h3>

                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div id="my_camera"></div>
                            <br/>
                            <input type=button value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
                            <input type="hidden" name="image" class="image-tag">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div id="results">Your captured image will appear here...</div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </fieldset>
```

I also included webcam.js right at the beginning of my body tag

```
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcamjs/1.0.25/webcam.min.js"></script>
...
```

Lastly, I included the script tag for custom functions within the body tag:

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
        Webcam.set({
            width: 300,
            height: 200,
            image_format: 'jpeg',
            jpeg_quality: 90
        });

        Webcam.attach('#my_camera');

        function take_snapshot() {
            Webcam.snap(function(data_uri) {
                $(".image-tag").val(data_uri);
                document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = '<img src="' + data_uri + '"/>';
            });
        }
    </script>
```

I have tried downloading and replicating the source code from [Savani H.](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-webcam-capture-image-and-save-from-cameraexample.html) (2018)'s article and his code seems to work well. Did I miss anything? Any help/insight would be appreciated.

**Reference:**
[Savani H.](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-webcam-capture-image-and-save-from-cameraexample.html) (2018)